# Zsh: =() substitution with executable permission

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, filesystems, zsh

I need to give an executable file to this command:

```
aria2c “some-url” —on-download-complete =(echo “!#/usr/bin/env bash
 touch success”)
```

Is this possible? If not, can I implement some helper functions to make something similar possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temporary file is not executable,

```
% stat -f '%Sp' =(echo echo echo)             
-rw-------
```

so will need to be marked as such somehow

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

TMPPREFIX=/because/tmp/is/mounted/noexec/on/my/system/tmp/zsh

fakearia () { $1 }

() {
   chmod +x $1
   fakearia $1
} =(<<EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo echo
EOF
)
```

here via an anonymous function which also helps better scope the temporary file and allows for any number of commands to happen on the filename.

Comment: I tested this with <(), too, but sadly that didn’t work.

Comment: @HappyFace With `<()`, you get a `/dev/fd/n` special file while fd n is open on the reading end of a pipe (`/dev/fd/n` being a special `/proc/self/fd/n` symlink to some sort of virtual named pipe on Linux, and an actual device file on other OSes, so even if you could change the permission of those files that would still not make it real executables).